# How can I solve np.where issue?

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause, conditional-operator

Hi everybody I am new at this forum, teaching technology since 2006 and before programming in diferent companies. I came from visual basic and now I am diving into python.
I have found the next problem when trying to use numpy **where** method.

```
 f"Cannot perform '{op.__name__}' with a dtyped [{x.dtype}] array "

TypeError: Cannot perform 'ror_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]
```

The code is this one

```
df['Value']=np.where((df['ValA']>0.01) & (df['ValB']>df['ValC']) & (df['ValB'].shift(1) > 0.8) & (df['ValB'] < 0.8) & (df['ValD'] > 0.02 | df['ValD'].shift(1) > 0.02 | df['ValD'].shift(2)> 0.02), 1, 0)
```

Everything was working fine untill I used =>

```
(df['ValD'] > 0.02 | df['ValD'].shift(1) > 0.02 | df['ValD'].shift(2)> 0.02)
```

as a part of the operator

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I believe the `|` operator has higher precedence than `>` operator (due to it being intended as bitwise but stats libraries use it for element wise logical) so you would need to parentheses the comparisons.

Comment: Perfect!!! I have tryied it, puting parentheses in each element before "|" operator as you said. It works fine. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate instead of "caused by typo" since linking this question to that one will likely be more helpful to others.